# Can I modify the keyboard shortcut for workspace switching?

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces

I use both OS X and Ubuntu(11.10).
In OS X, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> is the shortcut for changing space.
When I use Ubuntu, I habitually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to change space.
Actually I should use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.
Can I change the shortcut key?

Thanks.

Sam.

Answer (score 13):

1. Open the *Keyboard* utility.
2. In the *Shortcuts* tab, select *Navigation* and scroll to the bottom. Double click on a  row and press your new shortcut keys.

   [image]

Comment: I don't have this option listed in 21.10. Why does Ubuntu keep removing useful features GODDAMNIT