# 18.04 Change shortcut for switching workspace

Tags: workspace-switcher

I couldn't find a way to change the shortcut for moving between workspaces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>).
When I go to the keyboard settings, I can change the shortcuts which let me "jump" to a specific workspace, but there are no entries for "moving" between workspaces.
I also tried searching by shortcut, but e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> doesn't yield any results. The "Move..." entries visible in this post https://askubuntu.com/a/102289/458859 are simply missing.

I wonder if it is possible at all, to change

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Up  and  "Ctrl+Alt+Down using view Desktop screen

Comment: `Super + Page Up` and `Super + Page Down` respectively

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The setting is available, but  is not exposed in the user interface.

You can install dconf-editor to have a graphical interface to change a plethora of settings. The settings you are looking for are

`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Super>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']`

and

`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']`

You can change the assigned keys using dconf-edit. The settings can also be changed through the terminal with the command gsettings, e.g. the command

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down', '<Alt>d']"`

would add <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> as a shortcut key to switch to a workspace down.

One can reset a dconf setting to the factory default setting with `gsettings reset`, as in

`gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down`