# 18.04 Change Workspace Keyboard shortcut, conflicting with that for switching apps on the dash

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

I followed the steps mentioned in: [18.04 Change shortcut for switching workspace - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099107/18-04-change-shortcut-for-switching-workspace), to change Keyboard shortcuts to switch to another workspace, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

Most of the times this works. But, sometimes this shortcut that I have set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and so on conflicts with the other shortcut: The icons on the dash or Ubuntu Dock (on the left edge of the screen gets switched) as shown in the following figure: (You can observe that numbers appear at the bottom of each icon.)

[image]

**How can I completely disable or change the shortcuts to switch apps on the vertical dash, so that it doesn't conflicts with my workspace switching shortcuts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will disable the hot-keys behaviour.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

This command will disable the showing of numbers.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hotkeys-overlay false
```

[image]

If you want to change the shortcuts for these behaviours.

Open the `dconf-editor` (if not yet installed, use `sudo apt install dconf-editor`)

change the values like for example: app-hotkey-8 from `'<Super>'8` to `'<Ctrl>8'` or any valid shortcut your prefer.

[image]